# Return an array of class from method channel in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I am trying to return an array of class "Pair" from android host to Flutter client through the use of method channel. But I am getting the following error `Error retrieving id timestamp pairs: Unsupported value: 'com.example.my_app.Pair@f074fa2' of type 'class com.example.my_app.Pair'`

In android I have coded

```
public class Pair {
    final String key;
    final Long value;

    Pair(String key, long value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In the main activity that extends FlutterActivity I wrote

```
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler(
                    (call, result) -> {
                        // This method is invoked on the main thread.
                        switch (call.method) {
                            case "getPairs":
                                List<Pair> pairs = getPairs();
                                result.success(pairs);
                                break;
                            
                            
                            default:
                                result.notImplemented();
                                break;
                        }
                    });
}
```

In Flutter activity my code is

```
    Future<List<dynamic>> getIdTimestampsPairs() async {
    try {
      final List<dynamic> pairs =
          await _platform.invokeMethod('getIdTimestampPairs');
      return pairs;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      log('Error retrieving id timestamp pairs: ${e.message}');
      return [];
    }
  }
```

One solution obviously is to make two functions instead of one. One returning a list of keys and the other returning a list of values. Any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I returned one list of String where each element of string stores the value `key + " " + val`. And use `str.lastIndexOf(' ')` function in dart to separate the key and value. Then parsed the value using `int.parse()` function.